# Why is Laravel vendor:publish returning "Unable to locate publishable resources"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am implementing a package in Laravel 7 and using https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE as a reference.

Inside my package I have the following structure

```
packages/mypackage/src/MyServiceProvider.php
packages/mypackage/config/config.php
```

This is the the boot method from the serviceprovider

```
public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->publishes([
                $this->loadConfig() => config_path('myconfig.php'),
            ], 'config');
        }
    }
```

And this is the loadConfig() method

```
private loadConfig() {
        return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(
            __DIR__,
            '..',
            'config',
            'config.php'
        ));
    }
```

But when I run the following command from the root of the project, it is not working

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="MyPackage\MyPackageServiceProvider" --tag="config"

I get this error message

```
Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove vendor folder and composer.lock file and re-install all dependencies again?

Comment: I tried to remove the vendor folder and the composer.lock file and then run composer update, but afterwards I still get the same message

Comment: Is your file called config or myconfig.php?

Comment: No it is called config.php but when moved it should be named myconfig.php

Answer (score 6):

just run `php artisan vendor:publish` and choose the class that you want to publish. it's work for me on Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
 php artisan vendor:publish  --tag=config
```

and choose the class that you want to publish. it's work for me on

***Laravel 10***